# C++ Virtual clone method, exception inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, methods, virtual

I'm creating a virtual clone method in my class which I'm going to demonstrate in my main file. But when I try to do it I get errors.

Here's my class:

```
// includes

#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

namespace Vehicle_Renting {

   using namespace std;

    class Auto_Rent_Exception : public std::exception{
       protected:
          string error;
       public:
          Auto_Rent_Exception(){
          }

          virtual const string what() = 0;
          virtual ~Auto_Rent_Exception() throw();
          virtual Auto_Rent_Exception* clone() = 0;
    };

    class short_input : public Auto_Rent_Exception{
    public:
      short_input(const string errorMsg){
        stringstream ss;
        ss << errorMsg << ": short_input" << endl;
        error = ss.str();
      }
      virtual const string what(){
         return error;
      }
      virtual short_input* clone(){
         return new short_input(*this);
      }
    };
}
```

And here's how I'm using it:

```
cout << "Virtual Clone" << endl;
Auto_Rent_Exception* exc = new short_input("Smthing");   //Original copy
Auto_Rent_Exception* copy;
copy = exc->clone();
cout << exc->what();
cout << copy->what() << endl;
delete exc;
```

I get these errors which I don't know how to repair:

```
undefined reference to `vtable for Vehicle_Renting::Auto_Rent_Exception'
undefined reference to `Vehicle_Renting::Auto_Rent_Exception::~Auto_Rent_Exception()'
undefined reference to `vtable for Vehicle_Renting::Auto_Rent_Exception'
undefined reference to `Vehicle_Renting::Auto_Rent_Exception::~Auto_Rent_Exception()'
undefined reference to `Vehicle_Renting::Auto_Rent_Exception::~Auto_Rent_Exception()'
```

[Link to error image](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s490/sh/10b6d3d8-5508-4567-8888-84b932452d50/a5a2cd47d346206919444c41e1612fea)

Comment: Please copy and paste the error text so it becomes searchable. That said, I'm not sure std::exception is copyable. However, the issue is that there is no copy-constructor in *your* class taking a `short_input&`. That should be constant, too, otherwise you can't clone objects you only have a constant reference to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need a destructor:

```
virtual ~Auto_Rent_Exception()
{
}
```

Comment: But I have destructor it is : virtual ~Auto_Rent_Exception() throw(); If i changed I get error about loose throw.

Comment: That's just a promise of a destructor, a.k.a. declaration. You still need an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `Auto_Rent_Exception::~Auto_Rent_Exception()`.

`undefined reference to ...` error means that something is declared but not defined.